# On the datanode node of HDFS, if the core-site.xml configuration is modified, how can the configuration take effect without restarting the service?

Tags: hdfs, datanode

Are there any commands to make the `core-site.xml` configuration file take effect without restarting the service?

I've tried the command:

`hdfs dfsadmin -refreshNodes`

But it doesn't seem to work. Any suggestions? Thanks